# Telerik Kendo Grid PHP work properly in firefox but dosent show any data in chrome and ie

Tags: kendo-ui, grid

```
$transport = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceTransport();

$read = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceTransportRead();

$read->url('data')
 ->contentType('application/json')
 ->type('POST');

$transport ->read($read)
      ->parameterMap('function(data) {
          return kendo.stringify(data);
      }');
```

I use Above php code for get json data from routed data path to products.php by folllowing  code:

```
<?php

    $customers=DB::select('SELECT    Contactname,ContactTitle,CompanyName,Country FROM customers');
$count=DB::table('customers')->count();
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
echo "{\"total\":".$count.",\"data\":" .json_encode($customers)."}";

?>
```

In Firefox every thing is ok and grid show by json data but chrome and ie dosent show any data.

what is problem?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is Routing  $read->url('data')

i use 
    return view('sample'); 
in the route and this work in firefox but dosn't work in chrome

true is
    return response()->view('sample');